Structures declared in function prototypes
I have two functions. pos(), which defines a struct as its return type, and bar(), which defines a struct as an argument type:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static struct foo { int x; } pos(void)
{
    return (struct foo) {10};
}

static int bar(struct point { int x, y; } pt) 
{
    return pt.x + pt.y;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct foo a = pos();
    printf("a.x: %d.\n", a.x);
#if 0
    int sum = bar((struct point){10, 20});
    printf("sum: %d.\n", sum);
#endif
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

About which David R. Tribble here Incompatibilities Between
ISO C and ISO C++ says that the scope of the structure declared in either of these fashions does not extend outside the
function declaration or definition, making it impossible to define objects
of that structure type which could be passed as arguments to the function
or to assign function return values into objects of that type, and offers [C99: §6.2.1, 6.7.2.3, 6.7.5.3, I] as references.
But the former (struct foo) compiles and works perfectly fine (i.e. I am able to define objects of that structure type in main() can assign the function return value into an object of that type). GCC 13.1 and Clang 18.1 don't even
raise any warning.
The latter (struct point) on the other hand, fails to compile. Why does the first one work,
and the second one not? What are some possible use cases for these
"fashions"?

The struct point inside the #if 0 is not defined anywhere

@stark struct point { int x, y; } in bar()? But like the author and GCC and Clang say, that definition would not be visible outside of bar().

@stark I have explicitly mentioned that the first case (struct foo) compiles perfectly fine, but the second case (struct point) does not, whilst the author of the post states that the scope of the structure declared in either of these fashions does not extend outside the function declaration or definition. If what the author says is true, as per the references he provided, then the first case should not compile either.

The author of the post is wrong about the first case.

C allows both cases but the author is correct that defining the struct type within the parameter list limits the scope of the definition to be valid only within the function. Defining the struct type within the declaration of the function return type does not limit the scope of the struct type in C.

Although it may be legal, having a function define a struct is of limited utility. For struct point [if you could do this at all], you can only pass the struct by value. This is almost never done. To see why, try: struct point { int x,y; int data[1000000000]; } What is the real intent? To have opaque structs? If so, put struct foo; in a .h. Then, users of this can only pass around struct foo * but not dereference it. In foo.c, do: struct foo { int x,y; int data[1000000000]; }; Then, any function in foo.c can dereference the struct.

Regarding the linked blog, I once tried to create a wiki listing all the differences between news in C99 (compared to C89) and C++17 here: Are all of the features of C99 also in C++?

For starters the function prototype and the function prototype scope are two different notions.
The function prototype (the C Standard 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers):


...A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the
types of its parameters.


Such a function declaration can be at the same time a function definition.
As for the function prototype scope then

If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function
prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier has
function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function
declarator

That is the quote refers to function prototypes that are not at the same time their definitions.
Pay attention to that in your program example you do not have a
function prototype scope.
The structure struct foo is declared in the file scope.
static struct foo { int x; } pos(void)
{
    return (struct foo) {10};
}

So it is visible from its point of declaration.
As for the structure struct point then it is declared in the block scope of the function bar
static int bar(struct point { int x, y; } pt) 
{
    return pt.x + pt.y;
}

So it is invisible outside the function.
From the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has
file scope, which terminates at the end of the translation unit.

and


... If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which
terminates at the end of the associated block.



Let's take a closer look at 6.2.1p4 of C99.  It states:

If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function
prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier has
function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function
declarator.

struct point falls under this category since it is declared as part of the parameter list.  struct foo however is not part of a parameter list, but is the function's return type.  A few sentences up in 6.2.1 we also have this:

If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier
appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has
file scope, which terminates at the end of the translation unit.

Since struct foo is declared outside of a block and outside a list of parameters, it has file scope and may be used anywhere in the source file after it was declared.

I see, but what is the point of the allowing the second case (struct point)? Does it have a use I am failing to see?

@Harith Maybe you want to collate several values into a structure for readability and will only use the structure in this function.

@AndrewTruckle If the calling function does not know anything about struct point, how can it pass such a struct to bar()?

@Harith There is no point in allowing the second case. It just hasn't been explicitly disallowed by the language specification.

@Harith It's been around since at least C89, so there may be some historical basis for it.

@Harith why can’t the call re declare it as it calls it? I dunno

Read the actual standard (or at least the final draft), not random blog posts.

If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the associated block. If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier has function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function declarator.


"Read the actual standard" ==> It is not a light read most of the times. :)


David R. Tribble [...] says that the scope of the structure declared in either of these fashions does not extend outside the function declaration or definition,

As others observed, Tribble is incorrect with respect to this ...

static struct foo { int x; } pos(void) {
    // ...
}


... and he would also be incorrect with respect to this ...
static struct foo { int x; } pos(void);

.  In both of those cases, type struct foo is declared at file scope, and it can therefore be used elsewhere in the TU to declare objects of that type, such as to receive the return value from a call to that function.


making it impossible to define objects of that structure type which could be passed as arguments to the function or to assign function return values into objects of that type

Tribble is at best misleading about that.  C requires arguments to functions with in-scope prototypes to be of type that is assignment-compatible with the declared types of the corresponding parameters (C99 6.5.2.2).  That does not necessarily mean the same type* or even a differently-qualified version of the same type. For parameters declared with structure or union type, or types derived from such types, it very often isn't.
In particular, assignment compatibility (C99 6.5.16) for structure and union types and types derived from them is based on the general definition of "compatible type" (C99 6.2.7).  Two structure types declared in different TUs are compatible if they agree in

tag name, or absence of any tag

and if both are complete types,

number of members
member names
order of members
such that corresponding members of the two types themselves have compatible type.

That is certainly satisfied if the two definitions are lexically identical, such as from #including a header containing it, but that is not essential.
Now, I said Tribble was misleading here, not outright wrong.  He is technically right because because

the rules for structure type compatibility cover the same type and types declared in different TUs.  They do not cover multiple definitions in the same TU, even if their scopes do not overlap. In C99, then, if there is a structure definition with block or function prototype scope then there is no way to declare a compatible structure type elsewhere in the same TU. And,

the functions in question are declared static, so they cannot be called from another TU.


HOWEVER,

Otherwise identical external functions could be called with appropriate arguments from another TU, even according to C99 rules (with some care in how they are declared).

This quirk of the compatibility rules is largely a technicality, and it  will be removed in C2X for tagged structure types such as those in the question (C2X 6.2.7/1).

Prior to C2X, you're likely in practice to find the C2X type compatibility rule implemented as an extension by C compilers, if for no other reason than that it's simpler to support it than to not.




, and offers [C99: §6.2.1, 6.7.2.3, 6.7.5.3, I] as references.

And that goes to show you that you shouldn't trust someone just because they cite references (so check mine).  The claims you attribute to Tribble seem to rely on interpretations of the spec that are wrong in several particulars:

they partially misinterpret declaration scope
they misunderstand the circumstances under which two types are the same (this is clearer from the context of the larger article)
they probably do not appreciate the significance of compatible types to this analysis (but if they do appreciate that, then they sweep it under the rug)

With that said, however, Tribble's article seems overall to be pretty good.  I think this question hits on the most significant sore spot.

* Declarations of structure or union types in different scopes declare different types (C99 6.7.2.3/5), but not necessarily incompatible ones.
